# Why is the Maven surefire plugin creating two surefire* directories in the ${project.build.directory}?

Tags: maven-2, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I find this rather annoying. There are two surefire* directories in the target folder:

```
- surefire (empty)
- surefire-reports (containing the output of the tests)
```

I have tried finding the option to remove the `surefire` directory, but I can seem to find it.
The thing is -- I have other projects that don't have this empty directory, just the `surefire-reports`.

What do I seem to be doing wrong and how can I remove this? The main reason for me asking this is that this empty directory breaks my tab autocomplete in the console which sort of pisses me off, since the directory is empty.

In addition, this is just the test plugin, not the reporting one. There is no  section in the project (not any parent).

This is my surefire plugin setup:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>

                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*Abstr*Test*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I filed a ticket here:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the `maven-surefire-plugin` and I've filed a report under [SUREFIRE-846](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-846).

Answer (score 0):

"surefire" is a directory for temporary files created during surefire:test execution. These files are being deleted when Maven execution ends.

Comment: Well, the since the files are deleted, then the directory should also be removed after a successful execution.
It doesn't really make sense to have it there, if it won't be used.